# in debug mode i have very slowly connection with server

Tags: android, android-debug

I've developed an application for Android. My application connects with server. And it works very fast. But if I'm in debug mode the connection is very slow. Server sends me response, but client does not receive it for a long time. (1-3 minutes).

If I don't debug then everything works cool. I've tried on different devices. On dalvik and on AR`. Also I use DB ActiveAndroid, but in place where I debug, I do not use this.

```
04-14 10:01:01.140    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 21
04-14 10:01:01.140    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 22
04-14 10:01:01.140    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 23
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 24
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 25
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 26
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 27
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 28
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 29
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 30
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 31
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 32
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 33
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 34
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 35
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 36
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 37
04-14 10:01:01.150    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 38
04-14 10:03:27.530    7744-7865/com.skip.client.customer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5365K, 23% free 20033K/25792K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 39
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 40
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 41
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 42
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 43
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 44
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 45
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 46
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 47
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 48
04-14 10:04:13.970    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 49
04-14 10:04:13.980    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 50
04-14 10:04:13.980    7744-7751/com.skip.client.customer I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 51
04-14 10:05:55.330    7744-7865/com.skip.client.customer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5355K, 23% free 20061K/25808K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-14 10:08:24.410    7744-7865/com.skip.client.customer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5407K, 23% free 20045K/25844K, paused 36ms, total 38ms
```

Comment: Maybe your device generating a lots of logs in debug mode and the connection to the adb server is not so fast and the device is waiting for the  adb connection response and working on it, so your app maybe slow. i suggest you to tarce the CPU usage in the android device. and do keep in mind that you app will be slow while debugging and i have experienced it on my every app and it is common.

Comment: Nexus 6 slow?)))
Samsung Galaxy note 4?
Asus ZenFone 5

Comment: I did not mean them they are slow , that was just my guess, i may be wrong just check the cpu usage of your app of there may be issues with you abd connection the cable or adb server which runs on your PC/MAC/LINUX which causes the latency if the device doing error correction or waiting for a response from a slow adb connection. DISCLAIMER. All of the said above are just my guess. :)

Comment: What about the internet speed?Whether they vary in mobile and pc..Same problem occured to me...When i was using mobile..i switched on the mobile data 3g speed so used to connect to server really fast than my wifi connection...or you may have to check  each api used..how fast does each api works....if u have used many api's...

Comment: thanks for your advice. the fact that not all debug fast. How do I check what you expect?

Comment: try to put debug on specific point where exactly you want to check response.